# All connections to hub stuck/frozen. Websockets reconnect showing 404

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

We are facing a similar issue like this https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3353

When we start our application, after a while all the users connected to the hub start getting reconnecting issues.

In Chrome console all the users are seeing this continuously:

> jquery.signalR.min.js WebSocket connection to 'wss://[our site url]/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSocke…HcDfA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

All the users are stuck in reconnecting mode i.e this method is continuously firing for all users:

```
connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
                if (change.newState === $.connection.connectionState.reconnecting) {
                    failPendingMessages();
                    ui.showStatus(1, '');
                }
                else if (change.newState === $.connection.connectionState.connected) {
                    if (!initial) {
                        ui.showStatus(0, $.connection.hub.transport.name);
                        ui.setReadOnly(false);
                    } else {
                        ui.initializeConnectionStatus($.connection.hub.transport.name);
                    }

                    initial = false;
                }
                else if (change.newState === $.connection.connectionState.disconnected && initial === true) {
                    initial = false;
                }
            });
```

We are using that code from the Jabbr source code.

The state is changing from connected > reconnecting > diconnected> connected

Seems after a while when there are many connections, all the connections to Hub remain stuck i.e are not able to converse with hub properly and hence connection gets broken and we receive "WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" what I mentioned above.

Note that there is not a fixed time for this behavior/issue. Sometimes it starts with in few minutes of "application start" and sometimes it takes around 20-30 minutes.

This issue definitely seems to be because of many connections conversing at the same time to the Signalr core code via Hub.

Is there any fix for it?

Edit: We are using the latest version of Signalr i.e Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll (2.2.0)